# SharpGL. Отрисовать текстуру в квадрат

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

Возникла проблема с отрисовкой PNG/JPG изображения с применением библиотеки SharpGL. Каким образом это можно устроить?

Comment: [OpenGL на С#. Быстрый старт](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ih7gO5TU6dU).

Comment: Да, спасибо! Помогло.
[Время, с которого идет разбор использования текстур](https://youtu.be/Ih7gO5TU6dU?t=2980)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение оказалось примитивным.

1. Надо добавить в решение пакет SharpGL.SceneGraph (он содержит в себе
   удобную реализацию Texture)
2. Объявить, собственно, экземпляр Texture и загрузить в него изображение

```
texture.Create(gl, bitmap);
```

3. Обозначит OpenGL, что будем использовать текстуру при помощи кода

```
gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

4. Присоединить текстуру к OpenGL (еще до Begin())

```
 texture.Bind(openGL);
```

5. Отрисовать текстуру по координатам

```
var startX = this.X - width / 2;
var startY = this.Y - width / 2;

gl.TexCoord(0, 1); gl.Vertex(new[] { startX, startY });
gl.TexCoord(1, 1); gl.Vertex(new[] { startX + width, startY });
gl.TexCoord(1, 0); gl.Vertex(new[] { startX + width, startY + height });
gl.TexCoord(0, 0); gl.Vertex(new[] { startX, startY + height });
```

6. *Если нужно перейти после рисования текстуры к какому-то другому типу рисования, то

```
gl.Disable(OpenGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```